# Using Open Liberty with EclipseLink JPA provider - javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source not loading

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

Using Open Liberty version 21.0.0.12 with `jpa-2.2` configured among features and Derby DS config:

#### server.xml

```xml
  <featureManager>
    <feature>jaxrs-2.1</feature>
    <feature>jsonp-1.1</feature>
    <feature>cdi-2.0</feature>
    <feature>mpConfig-2.0</feature>
    <feature>jpa-2.2</feature>
  </featureManager>

  ...

  <dataSource jndiName="jdbc/JakartaEECafeDB">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="derbyJDBCLib" />
    <properties.derby.embedded databaseName="jakartaee-cafe-data" createDatabase="create"/>
  </dataSource>
```

and with my persistence.xml defined with:

#### persistence.xml

```xml
<persistence version="2.2"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
                        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="coffees" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/JakartaEECafeDB</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <properties>
        <property
            name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
            value="drop-and-create" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source"
            value="META-INF/initial-data.sql" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

my **initial-data.sql** script doesn't seem to get loaded.  The DB tables seem to get created but they are empty;  my script populated them with INSERT(s) doesn't seem to get run, and no obvious error appears even when turning Open Liberty JPA tracing on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Delete EclipseLink persistence property getting in the way

For me the solution was to delete the extra property:
`<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>`

Apparently it conflicted with the "javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" somehow?

So it works to just have:

```xml
<persistence-unit name="coffees" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/JakartaEECafeDB</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <properties>
        <property
            name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
            value="drop-and-create" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source"
            value="META-INF/initital-data.sql" />
        <!-- Delete
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
          -->
        ...
```

Comment: I believe this is a documentation error in EclipseLink. Looking at the source code (https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/eclipselink/blob/master/jpa/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa/src/main/java/org/eclipse/persistence/internal/jpa/EntityManagerSetupImpl.java#L4514), EclipseLink has a soft requirement that DDL generation properties (EclipseLink vs JPA Spec) not be mixed.

Comment: Maybe consider to use "jakarta" instead of "javax" namespace.